# Do I need a Javascript Closure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, closures, mouseover

For the below extra code, what is the better way to accomplish this. Do I need closures and if yes how?

I have a left side navigation and on mouseover I need to display the page contents. I have in css a class `.first{visibility:visible;top:150px;}`

This is what I am using to accomplish this.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function() {
        var $items = $("#sidebar > ul >li") 

        $("#mainabout").addClass("first");
        $(".about").mouseover(function() {
            $("#mainabout").addClass("first");
            $("#maineducation").removeClass("first");
            $("#mainexperience").removeClass("first");
            $("#mainprojects").removeClass("first");
            $("#maincontacts").removeClass("first");
            //$("#main").css("background-image","url('revoliution2010_btbg.png')");
        });

        $(".education").mouseover(function() {
            $("#maineducation").addClass("first");
            $("#mainabout").removeClass("first");
            $("#mainexperience").removeClass("first");
            $("#mainprojects").removeClass("first");
            $("#maincontacts").removeClass("first");
        });
        $(".experience").mouseover(function() {
            $("#mainexperience").addClass("first");
            $("#mainabout").removeClass("first");
            $("#maineducation").removeClass("first");
            $("#mainprojects").removeClass("first");
            $("#maincontacts").removeClass("first");
        });
        $(".projects").mouseover(function() {
            $("#mainprojects").addClass("first");
            $("#mainexperience").removeClass("first");
            $("#mainabout").removeClass("first");
            $("#maineducation").removeClass("first");
            $("#maincontacts").removeClass("first");
        });
        $(".contact").mouseover(function() {
            $("#maincontacts").addClass("first");
            $("#mainprojects").removeClass("first");
            $("#mainexperience").removeClass("first");
            $("#mainabout").removeClass("first");
            $("#maineducation").removeClass("first");

        });
    })
</script>
```

How do I made this jquery small and optimized or what is the better way to do this.

Comment: I'm seeing a pattern in that code. If you can see a patten in the code you can make it smaller. Post your HTML and give more details on what you're trying to accomplish. I'm assuming this is a menu

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with:

```
$(".education").mouseover(function() {
    $items.removeClass("first");
    $("#maineducation").addClass("first");
});
// etc..
```

You could abstract a step further with:

```
var regover = function (source, main) {
    source.mouseover(function() {
        $items.removeClass("first");
        main.addClass("first");
    };
};
```

Then your registration calls are merely:

```
regover($(".education"), $("#maineducation"));
```

Tiny!

Just make sure you define `regover` in the same scope where `$items` is defined.  That's what it means to be a "closure" -- the function references variables in an outside scope.  So for example:

```
var $items = ...;
var regover = function(source, main) { ... }
```

That way the function can "see" the `$items` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function, that removes all first classes. Now call this function before adding the one class you need.